# Good venue to find online tutor in mathematical statistics?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian

I've been having trouble finding a qualified online tutor to work with me on NHST vs. Bayesian concepts and experimental design. I'm sure there must be people around & available with real chops in mathematical statistics who are also excellent teachers. So far, I haven't found an online-tutor service whose tutors are advanced enough to assist.

To give a flavor of what I'm looking for, here are a couple of papers that I would love to discuss in detail with someone who really gets the concepts and conclusions and can effectively handle deep Q&A on both..

[Too Big to Fail: Large Samples and the p-Value Problem](http://galitshmueli.com/system/files/Print%20Version.pdf)

[Calibration of p Values for Testing Precise Null Hypotheses](http://www.dcscience.net/Sellke-Bayarri-Berger-calibration-of-P-2001.pdf)

The Stack Exchange job postings all seem to be programming-oriented. I'm definitely looking for someone who is very proficient in R and/or MATLAB. A lot of my self-study is focused on developing simulations to get an empirical understanding of whatever concepts I'm working on. However, I'm wondering if most of the Stack Exchange job seekers mainly identify as programmers first? In this case, I might be better off looking somewhere else.

I don't see any job postings here on Cross Validated. I've talked to the American Statistical Association about their JobWeb site, but they don't recommend it for me (it's geared towards full-time positions). According to ASA, the hourly pay I'm offering is upper-bracket. I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions or references.

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else here, but my advice would be to go to your local university math department and inquire about their tutoring services there. Grad students can be helpful, and the on-line format is not really suited for in-depth questions, especially since people don't know your math background.

Comment: Hi Rocinante, thanks for your comment. I've actually been working quite successfully with someone on-line for the last year, who I found on the now-defunct site TutorHero. Going forward, however, my current tutor no longer has enough time for me & we're reaching his limits math-wise anyway. But to your point, I respectfully disagree, having had numerous great in-depth discussions online about concepts and nuances.

Comment: I haven't scoured the internet to make a definite pronouncement, but all online tutoring services/sites I have come across on-line are geared towards freshman undergrads or secondary school students. Aside from StackExchange, I haven't come across any forum that deals with more advanced questions and have people with credible credentials. I can't see any reason why your local university math department wouldn't take you up on your offer, though. It would seem the fastest and easiest way to get your problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have actually been checking locally as well. Northwestern University, for example, prohibits their stats grad students from taking any outside work, since they get a stipend from the department & are expected to be focusing strictly on their own academics. My previous online tutor had been recognized within his university for excellence in teaching. So online does seem more promising.

Comment: Rocinante, I have to admit that I've only reached out to a handful of universities. I had a great talk with someone at the Univ. of Chicago Statistics dept. the other day about posting a job notice. So I would like to give you credit for your suggestion. Would you please post as a formal answer?

Comment: Sure, I will repost my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to go to your local university math department and inquire about their tutoring services there.

Grad students can be helpful, as well as post-grads. Depending on the types of questions you're asking and the speed with which you need an answer, the on-line format may not be suited for in-depth questions, especially since people don't know your math background.

As you said in your comments, some schools frown upon its graduate students working, so checking with post-doc people might also be an option.